# Can I use the concept of dimensional analysis in problems of vector analysis?

Tags: electric-fields, dimensional-analysis

For example if I have Gauss' law: $\nabla D=\rho_v$ how can I get one side from the other dimensionally?
Same question goes for rotation and generally for operators.
Please explain downvotes if there's any! I'm not the kind to downvote back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, recall the limit definition of a derivative, namely

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \lim_{\delta t \to 0}\frac{f(t+\delta t)-f(t)}{\delta t}$$

if taken with respect to time. From this, it is immediately clear that $\frac{df}{dt}$ has dimensions of $f$ over dimensions of time, so $\frac{d}{dt}$ can be thought of as having dimensions $[T]^{-1}$.

---

Now, we have Gauss' law, $\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$. The divergence is explicitly,

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}$$

and so each term has dimensions of the electric field divided by dimensions of length. We know that the dimension of the permittivity of free space is,

$$[\epsilon_0] = [L]^{-3}[M]^{-1}[T]^2[C]^2$$

where $[C]$ is the dimension of charge. We also know $[E] = [M][L][T]^{-2}[C]^{-1}$ and $[\rho] = [C][L]^{-3}$. So we find unsurprisingly that the dimensions on both sides of Gauss' law are consistent. If we knew the right hand side depended only on $\rho$ and $\epsilon_0$, then using dimensional analysis we would find $\rho/\epsilon_0$ is the only consistent right hand side dimensionally, up to a constant.